# VBA to save Excel theme, including both theme and custom colors

Tags: excel, vba, themes

I am trying to write a macro to save the theme from one Excel workbook and copy into another one. Unfortunately it only copies the theme colors, not our custom color palette. If I save the current theme manually, the custom colors are also saved. This is the code that doesn't work:

```
 sThemeFile = (Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Excel.thmx")

 ActiveWorkbook.Theme.ThemeColorScheme.Save sThemeFile
```

The theme file created only includes the theme colors and does not appear in the list of available custom themes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work if you copy the theme manually using [these](https://support.microsoft.com/office/change-the-appearance-of-your-worksheet-27a828f2-0c29-4269-88e4-27f67746e96d) instructions?  I've never actually worked with themes but the [`Workbook.ApplyTheme` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.applytheme) seems like it could be relevant.

Comment: Saving the theme using those instructions saves all the colors. Saving it with vba only saves the theme colors (top line of colors). The Workbook.ApplyTheme method works, but it only applies the theme that was saved: just theme colors when saved using VBA method or all colors (theme and custom) if the theme was saved manually.